# Is self intersection still homeomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am not sure how to aptly phrase my question, but if we have a surface and we self intersect a part of it, will it still be homeomorphic to our original surface?

[image]

I ask because in obtaining a Klein bottle, we allow such a self intersection of a cylinder as shown in the image above. One could say that this is simply a process of creating a Klein bottle and that the cylinder is no longer homeomorphic to what we have in the image. But I am also trying to show that a projective plane with one hole is homeomorphic to a Klein bottle. A projective plane with one hole can be thought of as a disc $D^2$, identifying antipodal points on $S^1 \subset D^2$, with a hole in it. This can be thought of as a cylinder as well by considering the boundary of the disc as one hole and the hole as well another hole.

If after self intersection our surface is homeomorphic then this makes sense to me. But why is this a homeomorphism? It seems as if were identifying random sections of our surface with each other, which doesn't seem to be homeomorphic.

Comment: FWIW the Klein bottle does not self-intersect.  The image you've included is an *immersion*; it's a map from the Klein bottle to $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is *locally* (but not globally!) injective.

Comment: @JacobManaker Why not an official answer?

Comment: @Paul Frost: (1) b/c the OP's question is more general than just the Klein bottle; they ask about self-intersecting *any* surface.  (2) b/c I can't follow the OP's discussion of the projective plane, so I don't feel confident answering an XY problem

Comment: @JacobManaker It is okay if you do not feel confident. Nevertheless I encourage you to give an answer. What you said in your comment is absolutey correct and it is *the answer* in the general case. Obviuosly the OP does not distinguish between a surface and its *images* under immersions.